# Example of how to create a Pivot Table in ClosedXML

Tags: excel, pivot-table, closedxml

We are using ClosedXML to generate .XLSX spreadsheets because it is small, nimble, and quick.  It appears that all the pivot table classes and methods are there in the API, but there is no documentation or examples on how to go about (in the correct sequence) creating pivot tables.  Our attempts at guessing have produced files that when opened, give an error about XML corruption, and Excel prompts you to delete the pivot table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure at what version [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) implemented Pivot Tables, but as of at least v0.70 they have been implemented. An [example](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pivot%20Table%20example) can be found in the [ClosedXML Documentation](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation). Below is an C# example I'm using in my own project.

```cs
IXLWorksheet xlPvSheet = xlBook.Worksheets.Add("Pivot");
IXLPivotTable xlPvTable = xlPvSheet.PivotTables.AddNew("PivotTable", xlPvSheet.Cell(1,1), xlForecastSheet.Range(1, 1, r, 11));
xlPvTable.RowLabels.Add("Box Type");
xlPvTable.RowLabels.Add("Box Color");
xlPvTable.ColumnLabels.Add("Request Date");
xlPvTable.Values.Add("Total Boxes");
```

Comment: Thanks!  Too bad they didn't have it in the timeframe for my project, but I may use it in the future.

Comment: I know this is old, but does `xlForecastSheet.Range` include the title of the table? So `(1, 1) until `(r, 11)` is the entire range of the table including the column titles?

Comment: @Jimenemex, I'm not sure I understand your question. If you mean column headers as opposed to title, then yes the range includes the headers.

Comment: @DrewChapin Yes, that's what I was looking for thanks.

Comment: @Jimenemex, If the index being `1,1` is what threw you off, ClosedXML indexes are 1 based instead of 0 to stay consistent with Excel. You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML/Excel/Ranges/XLRange.cs) it will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if you specify an index `<= 0`.

Comment: @DrewChapin No, my problem is I'm trying to add a PivotTable based off another table. Excel opens but repairs and removes my PivotTable because of unreadable content. Only happens when I go from `(1, 1, end, 6)`. It'll work for `(1, 1, end - 1, 6)`. The table is unreadable when going from `beginning` to `end` of the table range, but is readable when going from `beginning` to `end - 1`. I thought it was because I was including the column headers, but It's not that. The only differences of my version and the example is I'm adding `RowLabels` only. Also I populate my table from a `DataTable`

Comment: @Jimenemex, if you can share your code on a new question, I can try to help.

Comment: @DrewChapin Only if you have time, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007717/creating-pivot-table-using-closedxml) it is. Thanks.