# Creating pivot table using ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I'm trying to create a Pivot table using ClosedXML V0.91.1, but I keep getting problems with my excel file having unreadable content and then the excel workbook removing my pivot table when clicking `Yes` below.

[image: Error when opening excel file]

Below is that shows when I hit `Yes`. It's removing my pivot table.

[image: Excel removing unreadable content]

My Pivot Table is getting data from a table that is created from a history of TFS [Changesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb170151(v=vs.120)). The changesets are set into a `IEnumerable<Changeset>` which is then converted into a `DataTable` object which include the column headings.

A table is then created from the `DataTable` which is the source of the `PivotTable`. This is the code that I'm using:

```
public bool CreateReport(IEnumerable<Changeset> changesets)
{
    workbook = new XLWorkbook();
    var sumSheet= workbook.Worksheets.Add("Summary");
    // Converting IEnumerable<Changeset> into DataTable
    DataTable changesetTable = ConvertToDataTable(changesets);
    // Table
    var sumTable = sumSheet.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(changesetTable.AsEnumerable(), "SummaryTable", true);
    // Table - Formatting table
    tableWithData.Column("A").Cells(firstRow, lastRow).DataType = XLDataType.Number;
    tableWithData.Column("C").Cells(firstRow, lastRow).DataType = XLDataType.DateTime;
    tableWithData.Column("C").Cells(firstRow, lastRow).Style.DateFormat.Format = "d-MMM-yyy";

    sumSheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();

    // Pivot Table
    var header = sumTable.Range(1, 1, 1, 6); // A1 to F1
    var range = sumTable.DataRange;
    var dataRange = sumSheet.Range(header.FirstCell(), range.LastCell());

    var pivotSheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("History Report");

    var pivotTable = pivotSheet.PivotTables.AddNew("PivotTable", pivotSheet.Cell(1, 1), dataRange);

    // Pivot Table - Formatting table
    pivotTable.ShowPropertiesInTooltips = false;
    pivotTable.RepeatRowLabels = false;
    pivotTable.ShowGrandTotalsColumns = false;
    pivotTable.ShowGrandTotalsRows = false;
    pivotTable.ShowEmptyItemsOnRows = true;
    pivotTable.ShowEmptyItemsOnColumns = true;
    pivotTable.ShowExpandCollapseButtons = false;
    pivotTable.Layout = XLPivotLayout.Tabular;

    pivotTable.RowLabels.Add("Changeset");
    pivotTable.RowLabels.Add("Committer");
    pivotTable.RowLabels.Add("Date");
    pivotTable.RowLabels.Add("Comment");
    pivotTable.RowLabels.Add("File Changes");
    pivotTable.RowLabels.Add("Source");

    // Go off and save the workbook.
    bool saved = SaveFile();
    return saved;
}
```

I believe the problem is with how I am selecting the `dataRange` for the source of the Pivot Table.

```
    var header = sumTable.Range(1, 1, 1, 6); // A1 to F1
    var range = sumTable.DataRange;
    var dataRange = sumSheet.Range(header.FirstCell(), range.LastCell());
```

I followed the [example](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Pivot-Table-example) found on their wiki, but it gives those errors with my implementation. The only difference between my problem and the example, is that I am getting my source for the Pivot Table from a `DataTable`, and I am only inserting values into `RowLabels` in my Pivot Table.

If it helps, this is how I convert the `IEnumerable<Changeset>` to a `DataTable`

```
private DataTable ConvertToDataTable(IEnumerable<Changeset> changesets)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Changeset", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Committer", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
    table.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("File Changes", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Source", typeof(string));

    foreach(Changeset changeset in changesets) // Loop over all changesets
    {
        int changesetID = changeset.ChangesetId;
        string committer = changeset.CommitterDisplayName;
        DateTime creationDate = changeset.CreationDate;
        string comment = changeset.Comment;
        foreach(Change change in changeset.Changes) // Loop over all Changes in changeset
        {
            string filename = change.Item.ServerItem.Substring(change.Item.ServerItem.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            table.Rows.Add(changesetID, committer, creationDate, comment, filename, change.Item.ServerItem);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Some comments that are not related to your problem 

1) use a `using (var workbook...` for the XLWorkbook
2) The `DataTable` isn't required. You can insert the `IEnumerable<>` directly.
3) `header`, `range`, `dataRange` isn't required, you can pass sumTable.AsRange() as the pivot table source. (I have to update the wiki)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, a pivot table in ClosedXML should have at least one value field.

```
pivotTable.Values.Add("somefield");
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I am a bit late on this one, but in case anyone else tries to do this in future, my solution was as follows.

```
IXLPivotTable xlPvTable = TargetWorksheet.PivotTables.Add(
    "PivotTable123", 
    TargetWorksheet.Cell(1, 1), 
    SourceWorksheet.Range(1, 1, MainData.Rows.Count, MainData.Columns.Count)
);
```

Then add the `ColumnLabel` and `RowLabel`s etc..